# Iteration over nested arraylist structure shows unexpected results

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a nested arraylist structure over which I need to iterate. See the following:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<SubjectnameandMark>> level2arraylist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<SubjectnameandMark>>();
```

Then I have the following arraylists that I would add to the `level2arraylist`

```
ArrayList<SubjectnameandMark> st1 = new ArrayList<SubjectnameandMark>();
ArrayList<SubjectnameandMark> st2 = new ArrayList<SubjectnameandMark>();
ArrayList<SubjectnameandMark> st3 =new ArrayList<SubjectnameandMark>();
```

My SubjectnameandMark class is given below:

```
public class SubjectnameandMark
{
 String name;
 double mark;

 SubjectnameandMark(String name, double mark)
 {
  this.name=name;
  this.mark=mark;
 }

}
```

I am adding the subject names and marks to each student(st1, st2...) arraylist in the following way:

```
SubjectnameandMark sub1 = new ServtermnameandWeight("math",1.0);
SubjectnameandMark sub2 = new ServtermnameandWeight("geo",1.0);
SubjectnameandMark sub3 = new ServtermnameandWeight("physics",0.389);

st1.add(sub1);
st1.add(sub2);
st1.add(sub3);

............
```

Note that this process is repeated for all st that is st1, st2, st3....

Finally I am adding all st arraylists to `level2arraylist` with the following:

```
level2arraylist.add(st1);
level2arraylist.add(st2);
level2arraylist.add(st3);
....................
```

Now I am trying to iterate over these nested arraylist to see the subject name and marks:

```
for (l=0;l<level2arraylist.size();l++)
    { 
    for(n=0;n<level2arraylist.get(l).size();n++)
     { 
      studenttomatch= level2arraylist.get(l);
      Iterator<SubjectnameandMark> itr=studenttomatch.iterator();  

      while(itr.hasNext())
        { 
        SubjectnameandMark st=(SubjectnameandMark)itr.next();  System.out.println(st.servterm+" "+st.servtermweight);  
        }  
     }
    }
```

The problem is that not all subject and marks are shown. However, If I restrict the loop variable in the following way the specific record at that particular index is shown, for example I am only restricting to the first record (l=0;l<1) and the correct results are shown:

```
for (l=0;l<1;l++)
    { 
        for(n=0;n<level2arraylist.get(l).size();n++)
         { 
          studenttomatch= level2arraylist.get(l);
          Iterator<SubjectnameandMark> itr=studenttomatch.iterator();  

          while(itr.hasNext())
            { 
            SubjectnameandMark st=(SubjectnameandMark)itr.next();  
            System.out.println(st.servterm+" "+st.servtermweight);  
            }  
         }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for the double for-loop structure here since you're using an iterator. If you're iterating through all the elements in `level2arraylist`, then you don't need a for loop to iterate through all the elements in `level2arraylist.get(l)` because that's essentially what your iterator is doing. So simply just remove the inner for loop like so,

```
for (l=0;l<level2arraylist.size();l++)
{ 
     studenttomatch= level2arraylist.get(l);
     Iterator<SubjectnameandMark> itr=studenttomatch.iterator();  

     while(itr.hasNext())
     { 
         SubjectnameandMark st=(SubjectnameandMark)itr.next();  
         System.out.println(st.servterm+" "+st.servtermweight);  
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks. :). the inner for loop initially had another purpose in my old code.